# deploying dll to sharePoint 2007 just to the /bin and referncing from codebehind?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, dll, gac, code-behind

I recently changed desktops and Upgraded to Visual Studio 2010.. not remembering we need VS2005 for SharePoint development of webparts.  I've tried to deploy my webpart code from VS2010 and can't seem to do it.  But we are in the process of moving to SP 2010 so we should be okay for a few months and if need be I can start up my old desktop with 2005.

Anyways, some vendor sent me some dlls of some classes we can use to communicate with Outllook web services and I referenced them in vs2010 and they work great.

So I wanted to know if it would be possible for me to deploy those DLLs to my sharepoint environment and use them in codebehind.   I don't want to deploy them to the GAC, just the bin folder of the web ap, but would I need to create a safecontrol entry in my web.config and if so, where would I get the key for it?  I'm trying to do this without visual studio and just sharePoint designer 2007.

Possible? if so how using C# codebehind? What changes to web.config (if any) would I need? Where do I get the safecontrol key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MOSS 2007, use [WSP Builder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) to build your solution file.  You can create a folder called `bin` and place files in there that you want deployed to your bin folder.  The Safe Control entry will be automatically added to the web.config when you deploy the solution.